# Determine Euclidean distance in an image

Tags: image, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a doubt if there is a 100x100 image, say, T, where left half pixels are white (first 50 columns) and right half pixels are black (last 50 columns). If a new image, Tnew, of the same size, is formed from T by shuffling the pixel locations. Is it possible to determine the total number of possible Tnew images?. Let Euclidean distance between T and Tnew be D. Please let me know. Thank you.

Also, if there are any additional sources or reference links to explain this please do let me know. Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? It seems to be a basic statistics question. There’s an SE site for that too. Also, you’ll have to show your effort, now it looks like you just presented your homework and are hoping someone else will do it for you.

Comment: I completely agree with sir . With all due respect sir, I tried to come up with an approach regarding my doubt but I also needed a piece of expert advice too on this. So Ifor example if we had just 4 pixels, 2 white and 2 black, what would be the combination?.

Wwbb
wbbw
Wbwb
Bbww
Bwwb.                                                                                                                             
 To find the number of images we will need to work on find some combinations. Is this the right approach?